# The Semantic “MNIST” - Do you know similar projects?

Tags: machine-learning

Have you seen the movie, Rain Man? Do you remember the scene when Dustin Hoffman can count the exact number of toothpicks on the floor in the blink of an eye. This scene gave the idea to implement it as a machine learning example. We don't count toothpicks but points in an image.

In the classic [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) task, a typical classifier program takes images of handwritten digits and recognizes these digits. For example:

For [image] the MNIST classifier says it's 8

The "SMNIST" program doesn't take images of digits but images that contain less than 10 points:

[image] The "SMNIST" classifier should says it's 8

For further details see the blog post: https://bhaxor.blog.hu/2019/03/10/the_semantic_mnist
The sources can be found at https://gitlab.com/nbatfai/smnist
Here is an introductory video: https://youtu.be/-tSRwJgVpJk

Do you know similar projects or research?